# Django - How to group data from different models into one set of data?

Tags: python, django, templates, render

I'm new to this.. (Django and Stackoverflow)

I got this project, I want to display data from two different models as a set of data.

**template**

```
 <div>
 {% for j in Es %}
     {{ j.id }}
     {{ j.Entreprise }}
     {{ j.Ville }}<br />
     {{ j.Pays }}
     {{ j.Poste}}
     {{ j.Departement }}<br />
     {{ j.Redacteur }}
     {{ j.Debut }}<br />
     {{ j.Fin }}<br />
     <a style="color: #404040;" href="/cv/creer/Exptech/{{ j.id }}/{{ j.Entreprise }}/{{ j.Departement }}"> Decrire mon expérience technique</a><br />
     <a style="color:#404040;" href="/cv/creer/Expskil/{{ j.id }}/{{ j.Entreprise }}/{{ j.Departement }}"> Decrire mon expérience skills</a><br />
     <a style="color: #404040;" href="/deletex/{{ j.id }}/{{ j.Entreprise }}"> supprimer</a><br />
 {% endfor %}

 {% for s in Tecs %}
     {{ s.Entreprise }}<br />
 {% endfor %}
 </div>
```

**models.py**

```
class Experience (models.Model):
    Entreprise = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Ville = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Pays =  models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Poste = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    DEPARTEMENT_CHOICES = (
    ('Marketing','Marketing'),
    ('Finance','Finance'),
    ('Vente','Vente'),
    )
    Departement = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=DEPARTEMENT_CHOICES)
    Debut = models.DateField()
    Fin =   models.DateField()
    Auteur = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Entreprise

class Exptech (models.Model):
    Ids = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Entreprise= models.ForeignKey(Experience)
    Departement = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Auteur = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Exp1 = models.TextField()
    Exp2 = models.TextField()
    Exp3 = models.TextField()

class Skills (models.Model):
    Ids = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Entreprise= models.ForeignKey(Experience)
    Departement = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Auteur = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Exp1 = models.TextField()
    Exp2 = models.TextField()
    Exp3 = models.TextField()
```

**views.py**

```
def complete(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponse('<p> impossible dacceder a la page </p>')

    k = request.user.username
    ec = Etatcivil.objects.filter(Auteur=k)
    f = Formation.objects.filter(Auteur=k)
    E = Experience.objects.filter(Auteur=k)
    Tec = Exptech.objects.filter(Auteur=k)
    Ski = Skills.objects.filter(Auteur=k)
    return render_to_response('cv/cv.html', {'ecs':ec, 'fs': f, 'Es': E, 'Tecs': Tec, 'Skis': Ski})
```

All of this set my question is :

On the models : Exptech and Skills classes depend on the Experience class (ForeingKey relationship) 
In my template, when I render the view, i get a list of Experience and then a list of Exptech objects.

I don't want to have this list, but a pair of " Experience" and "Exptech" objects where Exptech objects depends on Experience object. Not the all "Experience" objects before the all "Exptech" objects.

I can't find how to do this...

Is someone can help me with it? I will give more information if needed I'm not sure if this is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
{% for s in Tecs %}
{{ s.auteur }} <-----> {{ s.enterprise.ville }}
{% endfor %}
```

More info on foreign keys here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey

And I also guess that you would like to make a separate model from the fields like Auteur, as you're using it between other models widely.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But when I render it the " <----->" appears. I think it should not right?

Comment: Just remove it! :) It doesn't contain any sense, just my remark to show the connection between the objects. So, it works as you expected?

Comment: Sorry... but looking at it again I find one things that does not work.. I only want the data from Expskill that corresponds to the Experience. But when I add another Experience, I get a list of two Expskill under each experience. I want to have one Experience, with only one Explskill (the one that corresponds) and not the one that corresponds AND the one of the other experience.